# Cannot init struct in if construct in Go

Tags: struct, go, initialization

I got a great surprise when I noticed the following snippet not compiling:

```
aTime := time.Time{}
if defaultTime := time.Time{} ; aTime != defaultTime {}
```

The compiler returns:

> type time.Time is not an expression
>
> defaultTime := time.Time used as
>
> value undefined: defaultTime

The intent here is to test the *aTime* variable if it's set to it's default value.

It also does not compile if I get the pointer of the struct (*defaultTime := &time.Time{}*).

However, it does compile if I init defaultTime outside of the if construct, or do the init using the new() builtin:

```
aTime := time.Time{}
if defaultTime := new(time.Time) ; aTime != *defaultTime {}
```

From what I've read everywhere, *new(myStruct)* it supposed to be completely equivalent to *&myStruct{}*.

As I interprate it, *defaultValue := time.Time{}* qualifies as a [SimpleStmt](https://golang.org/ref/spec#SimpleStmt) (specifically an [Assignment](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignment)), as detailed in the [If statement spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#If_statements).

I've come up with no explanation for this behavior, despite my best googling efforts. Would be grateful if someone could make my head stop spinning.

Comment: Better would be to use [`Time.IsZero()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.IsZero). For example `fmt.Println(time.Time{}.IsZero())` prints `true`.

Comment: Thanks for that remark @icza, I'll put it to use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `{` is recognized as the beginning of a `Block`, terminating the parsing of the `SimpleStmt`. After committing to that decision, the compiler decides that, as a `SimpleStmt`, `aTime := time.Time` isn't valid because `time.Time` isn't a value that can be assigned. However, it's presumably too late for the parser to try another interpretation of the `{`.

The version with `new` works because it doesn't contain a `{` character, and so avoids confusing the parser in this way.

You can also use the literal format by wrapping it in parentheses, because a block can't legally begin in the middle of an expression, so this also works:

```
if defaultTime := (time.Time{}); aTime != defaultTime {
    // ...
}
```

`gofmt` gives the helpful message "expected boolean expression, found simple statement (missing parentheses around composite literal?)", but oddly, the go compiler itself does not.

Comment: This info is found in the Go spec in the last few paragraphs of the Composite Literals section (https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals). Do a find for "A parsing ambiguity arises when" to skip to the right paragraph.

Comment: OK, so technically, this is a bug/shortcoming in the go lexer? Good to see it's documented (although I failed to find it). Wrapping looks like a passable alternative for when new cannot be used (for the cases where fields need to be set). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what I am going to suggest is necessarily a better solution. But for your use case, you can try this to be concise

```
if !aTime.IsZero() {
    // ...
}
```

Ymmv